# Powershell: Textfile with out-file and concats

Tags: file, powershell, variables, concatenation

Hello stackoverflowers,

I am trying to make .txt to a specific path.

Several variables will be included in the name of the text file.

First I put the path into a variable. Then I have concatenate the variables that I want to have in the name of the file.

```
############ Variables ###############

 $TheYear = Get-Date -UFormat "%Y"
 $TheTime = Get-Date -UFormat "%T"
 $TheDay = Get-Date -UFormat "%A"
 $TheDate = Get-Date -UFormat "%D"
 $TheMonth = Get-Date -UFormat "%B"
 $TheMachine = $env:COMPUTERNAME
 $TheUser = $env:USERNAME
 $TheFourtyTwo = "R:\Powershell\" + $($TheUser) + "_" + $($TheMachine) + "_" 
 + $($TheDate) + "_" + $($TheTime) -replace "-", ""
```

(The other variables will be displayed in the textfile, but I am not that far yet.)

With Write-Output I see the path and the filename I want to have:

```
R:\Powershell\Schmidt.M_WOPCC2407032_10.05.17_09:08:27
```

Within a function I try to make the .txt.

```
########## TXT.File With Computername and Execution-Time ################

    function Write_Output(){

        Out-File -filepath "$($TheFourtyTwo).txt" -append

    }
```

But I am not sure why I don't get the file, when I open the folder. 
Maybe I confused myself too much, because I have seen and tried a lot of ideas.

I would be very happy about a little thrust in the right direction.
Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file system does not support colon (:) in file name.

I would recommend to replace them... 
E.g.:

```
R:\Powershell\Schmidt.M_WOPCC2407032_10.05.17_09-08-27
```